# VBScript/ASP-Classic "Stop" Statement Not Breaking Into Debugger

Tags: debugging, asp-classic, vbscript

I've used to put a "`stop`" statement in my VBScript/ASP-Classic code to break into debugger (Microsoft Script Editor, that comes with Microsoft Office).

But now it isn't breaking anymore. The "`stop`" is ignored and nothing happpens.

The server-side debugging flag is already enabled in IIS

How to solve this?

---

Sample Code, `hello.asp`

```
stop 
Response.Write "Hello W."
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue. I'm running classic ASP from IIS. IIS has "enable server-side debugging" enabled. `stop` and exceptions don't cause Windows to prompt me on how to handle the issue. If I connect Visual Studio to the IIS process for debugging, if I set break points it says no symbols are loaded.

Answer (score 2):

Are you running VBScript in an Office app?  Wouldn't that be VBA?

For VBScript debugging you need to enable that with the /d switch on with wscript or cscript when running the vbs file:-

```
 wscript /d c:\myfolder\myscript.vbs
```

**Edit**:  Did I miss the ASP-Classic bit?

In this case you have turned off debugging in the application configuration.
In IIS6 open properties on the ASP application, select Home Directory tab, click "Configuration..." in the Application Settings section.  Select the Debugging tab, select the debugging flags.

Comment: You are right... But actually I'm runnig it from a ASP page. Any ideas?

Comment: Those flags are all set in IIS.

Comment: Actually there is... "Error: The Template Persistent Cache initialization failed for Application Pool 'DefaultAppPool' because of the following error: Could not create a Disk Cache Sub-directory for the Application Pool. The data may have additional error codes.."

Comment: I've follow those instructions, the message in event log stopped, but the debugger didn't started... :(

Comment: Are you getting the Response.Write output or is the page not working?
What happens if you deliberately include an error such as a divide by zero>

Comment: The stop is simple ignored... the rest of the script works normaly. If I put a "divide by zero" error I get "Microsoft VBScript runtime error"

Comment: Check the registry key: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AeDebug  what are the Auto and Debugger settings?  Can you think of what conditions have changed from when it was working?  Has there been IISRESET or even a Re-boot since the problem arose?

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead of `Stop`:

```
Dim I
I = 1 / 0
```

Answer (score 1):

It may be a problem with the Registry - See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/252895